# Dimple Specific Axis Variable Value

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

My Data is nested in the hopes of adding in a value slider to dynamically change the year. One entry looks like:

```
key: "dot1"
values: Array[3]
 [0]: Object
   x: 3
   y: 2
 [1]: Object
   x: 2
   y: 5
 [2]: Object
   x: 3
   y: 5
key: "dot2"
etc...
```

Is there a way to access the values to graph? Something like:

```
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, rawData);
chart.setBounds(90, 35, 480, 325)
var myyAxis = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "values[0][y]");
var myxAxis = chart.addMeasureAxis("x", "values[0][x]");
chart.addSeries(["key"], dimple.plot.bubble);
chart.draw(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a computed string as a measure property, so the easiest way I know to accomplish this is to format the data to flatten out your internal arrays, so instead of

```
key: "dot1"
values: Array[3]
 [0]: Object
   x: 3
   y: 2
 [1]: Object
   x: 2
   y: 5
 [2]: Object
   x: 3
   y: 5
```

you end up with

```
[
{ 'key' : 'dot1', 'x' : 3, 'y' : 2 },
{ 'key' : 'dot1', 'x' : 2, 'y' : 5 },
{ 'key' : 'dot1', 'x' : 3, 'y' : 5 },
]
```

I got a basic example of this working here : http://jsbin.com/rijuvoneyu/1/edit?js,output

It uses underscore.js to map each row in the dataset, map each value array inside (so for every 1 row in the dataset you end up with 3), then flatten the entire structure out. Now you can just use 'x' and 'y' as the properties for the measure axes.
You'll notice I added a unique identifier for each new data row. Without that, if I only did

```
var series = chart.addSeries(["key"], dimple.plot.bubble);
```

dimple was adding all the values sharing the same 'key' together, so only plotting two bubbles. I'm not sure if there is a better way to not have that happen without the unique id, but it works well enough.